# bash: do not show the part of the line that is in the search terms of the grep command

Tags: command-line, 20.04, text-processing, grep

For example I have a directory:

```
/A/B/C/D/E/F/G.txt
```

Not knowing a priori `/E/F/G.txt`, I need to isolate that part. For ease of example:

```
echo '/A/B/C/D/E/F/G.txt' | grep -o '/A/B/C/D'
```

Shows:

```
/A/B/C/D
```

But I want:

```
/E/F/G.txt
```

With:

```
echo '/A/B/C/D/E/F/G.txt' | grep -o -v '/A/B/C/D'
```

I don't get the desired output (the output is not there at all).

How can I get the desired output using `grep`, i.e. not showing the part of the line which is in the search terms of `grep`?

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Please post the script you have written not just what you want it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With PCRE expressions, you can specify a pattern but exclude it from the match using `\K`:

```
% echo '/A/B/C/D/E/F/G.txt' | grep -Po '/A/B/C/D\K.*'
/E/F/G.txt
```

However, if this is actually for files and directories, I'd suggest using `find` instead:

```
% mkdir -p A/B/C/D/E/F
% touch A/B/C/D/E/F/G.txt
% find A/B/C/D -type f -printf "%P\n"
E/F/G.txt
```

Or if you really want the leading slash:

```
% find A/B/C/D -type f -printf "/%P\n"
/E/F/G.txt
```

From [the `find` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Name-Directives):

> `%P`
>
> File’s name with the name of the
> command line argument under which it was found removed from the
> beginning.

Comment: But won't your `find` just output any files below `/A/B/C/D`? I understand the question like OP has a file path and wants the path of the file relative to a fixed parent directory.

Comment: @pLumo they do say "Not knowing a priori /E/F/G.txt" ... which I take to mean that what exactly that is is also something they need to discover (which they'll likely do using `ls`, `find` or something similar, in which case just using `find` for the whole job is easier)

Comment: But OP also says, "I have a directory", which I understand as that this is part of a script and the information comes from some input before. Anyways, OP will be able to tell I guess ;-)

Comment: PERFECT!!! BOTH WORKS FINE!! I CHOOSE FIND. Yes, I want the leading slash. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `realpath`:

```bsh
file=/A/B/C/D/E/F/G.txt
realpath --relative-to="/A/B/C/D" "$file"
```

(needs `-m` if that is not a real file.)

Output:

```
E/F/G.txt
```

Comment: This is a good solution, thanks.